# Append specific range to CSV

Tags: excel, database, vba, csv, append

I am trying to append the excel table below (skipping the header) to a CSV file.

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgRyn.jpg)

I have the following code, but it appends only Range "U2". If I select "U2:AF2", it throws a debug error.

```
Sub AppendtoCSV()
    Dim strFile_Path As String
    strFile_Path = "\\cpath\SAV_QC.csv"
    Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
    Write #1, Sheets("SAV_QC").Range("U2")
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Is there a specific way to set Range for Write function or is there a better way to append specific range to CSV which will be imported in Access?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the range in which you wish to write to your CSV file. Then copy over that selection to the file you just opened. Instead of a write to file try copying the cells.

Refer to your range like so :

```
Sheets("SAV_QC").Range("U2:AF2").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried specifying that range, but it still only appended U2 value and skipped V2:AF2.